# jQueryMobile: fixed footer glitches

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, footer

I'm experiencing some glitches with a fixed footer using jQuery Mobile (v1.4.5.) on a mobile website.

When there's a lot of text (which needs scrolling), there's no problem.
When there's few text (which doesn't need scrolling), there's no problem.

The glitch occurs when there's just enough text to require a little scrolling. What happens is that the footer disappears when scrolling back up and pops back on release. I'm testing this on Chrome (mobile on Nexus 5) and I think this has something to do with the fact that in Chrome, the address bar of chrome disappears on scrolling. When scrolling back up, the address bar appears again, resulting in disappearance of the footer.

I took the fixed footer demo page from jQuery Mobile and delete just enough text to make sure it's not my code, but even with this demo page, the problem persists.

Anyone knows a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fixed position footer, you could scale the page to fit the device height and make the content div scrollable (see Omar's article: https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/06/content-div-height-fill-page-height/):

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div id="jqmHeader" data-role="header" >
         <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>
    <div id="jqmContent" role="main" class="ui-content" >
       <!-- scrollable content here -->
    </div>
    <div id="jqmFooter" data-role="footer"> 
        <a href="#" data-role="button">Footer Button</a>
    </div>
</div>

function ScaleContentToDevice() {
    scroll(0, 0);
    var headerHeight = $("#jqmHeader:visible").outerHeight();
    var footerHeight = $("#jqmFooter:visible").outerHeight();
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

    var content = $("#jqmContent:visible");
    var contentMargins =  content.outerHeight() - content.height();

    var contentheight = viewportHeight - headerHeight - footerHeight - contentMargins;

    content.height(contentheight);
};

$(document).on( "pagecontainershow", function(){
    ScaleContentToDevice();        
});

$(window).on("resize orientationchange", function(){
    ScaleContentToDevice();
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/1b7v6jpo/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Didn't seem to work for me though, has scrolling issues too in Chrome (mobile).